# How to use jQuery code in Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make a datepicker in my View. So I changed TextBox to this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectDeadline, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectDeadline, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter date here..." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectDeadline)
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added this jQuery code to _Layout.cshtml :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(); 
    });
</script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

But it isn't working, I can't see any datepicker. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Did I place jQuery code somewhere wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is your `@RenderBody()` above or below your script tag?

Comment: It's above script tag, is that why?

Comment: I moved my jQuery script below `@RenderBody()`, nothing changed.

Comment: No, I do not see the `datepicker` script? is it in the jquery bundle or the bootstrap bundle?

Comment: It's not in any bundle...

Comment: And I don't know how to put it in a bundle either.

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there is no error...

Comment: what library is being called to instantiate the datepicker()?

Comment: I'm sure that datepicker plugin don't define in none of jquery and bootstrap library.Can you say, where were defined  datepicker plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I can think of only 2 reasons for that to fail.

**1)** You forgot to include the library where the datepicker functionality is defined. Make sure that you have jQuery UI library included in your page. It should be loaded after you include jQuery because jQuery ui is dependent on jQuery.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(); 
    });
</script>
```

I am loading the library from the jQuery cdn. If you have a bundle for this in your project, you can replace my new line with that.

**2)** You have some other script error in your page which is preventing the javascript code to fail. Open your browser console and see whether you have any errors.

If you do not have any script errors and you included jQuery UI library, date picker will work. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Loa0m) is a working sample. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code for View seems to be correct. Please check your Model for your datetime property it should look like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Even if this was the case, there is no reason the datepicker will be affected by the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` atribute